# Airpods w Android: on calls bluetooth constantly connects/disconnects

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, headset

HTC 10, Android 7.0

Works great for music playback, but on calls it continuously connects/disconnects the bluetooth.

So using the airpods are useless for calling.

I have tried unpairing/repairing, and turning off/on the "phone" option on the bluetooth settings.

This issue is widely reported on the web, with android generally. For example here: https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/apple-airpods-connection-issue.497047/

This vlogger says to use just one ear of the airpods for calls when using android.  https://youtu.be/YUI4aZ1Uer8   My first pass testing indicates that using one ear is indeed a work around (though audio quality was poor, not sure if as a result of the single side)

How to diagnose/resolve?